# Use jQuery .trigger to call a custom function that returns a value

Tags: jquery

Is there any way using jQuery's .bind() and .trigger() calls to execute a user defined function (ex: save ()) and act upon the return from the method?  For example:

```
$("#aForm").bind ('save', function () {
  return true;
});
```

and then:

```
if ($("#aForm").trigger ('save') == true) {
  doSomething ();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old, but maybe this can help someone.

As Paliath pointed, you can't return a value because the trigger event is asynchronous.
What you can do, is pass a object as parameter to the event. By default, javascript objects are always references to the original.

eg.:

bind:

```
$(...).bind('example',function (evt,ret) { 
    ret.val = false;
});
```

trigger:

```
var ret = {ret:true};
$(...).trigger('example',[ret]);
if (!ret.ret)
    //event return false
else
    //event returned true
```

Comment: Potentialy, yes. If used properly :)

Comment: Nope it wont. You pass the reference of the object (true) to the event trigger and trigger it. The event handler alters the value async with ajax to false. Let's say ajax completes in 10secs. So in 10 seconds the value will have become false. But you check it immediately after the trigger and you get a wrong value of true. I hope I was clear.

Comment: You can if you use `trigger` at the right time, just after ajax finishes.

Comment: Why do that and how to time that? Just use `triggerHandler` that will wait for the async call to complete.

Comment: I usually trigger it inside the "success" callback of the ajax call. That way make sure everything runs when it's supposed to.

Comment: Ok, I'm not following what are you aiming at to solve. Sorry, this may not work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), which in many other ways acts like `trigger()` but will allow you to return a value.

From the docs:

> The .triggerHandler() method behaves similarly to .trigger(), with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> - The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur (such as a form submission).
> - While .trigger() will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery object, .triggerHandler() only affects the first matched element.
> - Events created with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly,
>     they do nothing.
> - Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining), .triggerHandler() returns whatever value was returned by the last
>     handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it
>     returns undefined

Answer (score 4):

You can also use jQuery builtin [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [event.isDefaultPrevented()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/):

```
$("#aForm").bind ('save', function (event) {
    return true;
    // "return false" or "event.preventDefault()" have the same effect
  }
});
```

and then:

```
var event = $.Event('save')
$("#aForm").trigger (event)
if (event.isDefaultPrevented() == false) {
  doSomething ();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you act on the return value in the callback itself? It takes away the extra check (that won't work like you would expect it to).

```
$("#aForm").bind ('save', function () {
  if(some stuff happens that is true) {
      doSomething();
  }

  else {
      doSomethingElse();
  }
});
```

Callbacks don't work synchronously. They are used to handle things that happen asynchronously (like events). In they context of callbacks, they are pieces of code that run when something happens. Returning values from them really doesn't make sense. In your example, since you want to check on the return value of the callback, you can be sure that you *only* get a return value when the callback runs (because you're trying to use them like a regular function). In that case, put that logic inside the callback itself (like I have shown above).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing that for the simple reason that I have multiple forms in a dialog (each in a separate tab).  I'd like the dialog itself to handle actually calling each form's "save" method individually based on a "dirty" flag.  That's why I'm trying to abstract out the "doSomething()" and "doSomethingElse()" functions from the forms -- i.e. the main dialog handles the overall flow.  I just want each of the forms to handle saving their data -- or returning false if an error occurs when saving their data.  Is it possible to add a custom "save" function to each form using .extend()?

Comment: Why don't you have a validation method that handles validation. You should bind to your form's `submit` event and then run the validation. If the validation is successful, then submit the form.

Comment: Along that same vein, wouldn't it be possible for me to add a new function called 'save' or 'saveData' just like the validation plugin does to add a new capability to the form, and then use that method to save the data?  I've not made a plugin, but this seems the more elegant way to achieve what I was trying to do, no?

Comment: Sure, you can do that if you need to perform an AJAX request of some sort (or need to modify the data). But in general if you have bound to the `submit` event, you just need to return the result of the validation. The submit event is special in the sense that it inspects the return value of the handler to see if it needs to submit the form.