# Jquery: Returning Value From Trigger

Tags: jquery, triggers

I am using a trigger call a get a value from custom event but I want it to return a value and its only giving me Object Object when I do the following call:

```
var user_id=$("#my_div").trigger("get_id", [username]);
```

My trigger event function looks like this:

```
$("#my_div").on("get_id", function(e, username){
    var user_id;
    if (username='fred'){
        user_id=1;
    }
    else if(username='mario'){
        user_id=2;
    }
    return user_id;
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery .trigger to call a custom function that returns a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142724/use-jquery-trigger-to-call-a-custom-function-that-returns-a-value)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot return a value from a trigger, but you can store information in many different ways, one way is using a object as a parameter:

```
//event
$("element").on("click", function(event, informationObj) {
       informationObj.userId = 2; //you have to access a propery so you can modify the original object
});
//trigger
var informationObj = {userId : 0};
$("element").trigger("click", [informationObj ]); //informationObj.userId === 2
```

other way is using jQuerys `.data()` method

```
//event
$("element").on("click", function() {
     $(this).data("userId", 2); 
});
//trigger
$("element").trigger("click").data("userId") //2
```

Another thing you can do is modifying a variable that's declared outside the event and then using it after calling the trigger, **or** storing it as a property in the element that has the event with the `this` keyword like this:

```
//inside the event function
this.userId = 2;

//outside the event
$("element").trigger("click").get(0).userId
```

Hope it helps.

*Edit:*

Also, take a look at [@Arm0geddon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014591/437049) below, using `.triggerHandler()`, just beware that it has some side effects, like not bubbling up the DOM hierarchy.

Answer (score 26):

What you can do is use [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) instead of `.trigger()`. This will return a value.

```
var user_id=$("#my_div").triggerHandler("get_id", [username]);
```

Comment: Just beware that `triggerHandler` doesn't do the exact same thing as trigger, which can cause unintended bugs. The docs cover this differences, like not bubbling up the DOM hierarchy or not causing the default behavior of an event to occur.

Answer (score 2):

A trigger cannot return a response, because it's a callback method.

In addition jQuery have a fluid API, so `.trigger()` returns always `$(this)`.
You can write `$("#my_id").trigger(something).show().on(someelse)...`

Answer (score 1):

The `trigger` function doesn't return the value you return from the event handler.

It returns `jQuery object`...

> .trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] ) Returns: jQuery

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

This was designed so you could write things like this:

```
$("#my_div").trigger("get_id", [username]).val('foo').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Ok well in that case is there some way I could shove it into the Jquery object so that it would be accessible?

Comment: @Petty_Crim. It won't be a good idea, save it in a variable or a **hidden input**.

Comment: I guess I just assign it to a data object ie $("#my_div").data("user_id", user_id) but I was hoping there would be an alternative solution.

Comment: @Petty_Crim. There are "alternative solution" solutions, not necessarily better... that `data` idea of your's sounds good. Go with it. inside the handler you can write `$(this).data("user_id", user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#my_div").on("get_id", function(e, username){
    var user_id;
    if (username='fred'){
        user_id=1;
    }
    else if(username='mario'){
        user_id=2;
    }
    return user_id;
});

var user_id=$("#my_div").triggerHandler("get_id", ["username"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

triggerHandler is the correct answer, but it's worth noted as I have not seen it here yet...
You can pass another callback along as well, and have your "on" function call the passed callback to set some return value etc. assuming it's better not to wait for some reason.